# Как работает веб-сервер Apache? Параллельно выполняющиеся скрипты в Apache

Tags: php, apache, symfony

Есть php скрипт который обрабатывает данные из бд, и по определенному условию копирует их в бд другим записям. Этот скрипт запускается через браузер, по такому url (ЧПУ) - site.com/admin/hard_script, он достаточно длительный и тяжелый, ориентировочное время выполнения около суток. Но вот незадача, при его запуске сервер перестает обрабатывать запросы на другие страницы сайта, выводя ошибку 504  Gateway Time-out.

Нужно сделать так чтобы сервер параллельно выполнял бы этот скрипт и обрабатывал бы запросы по другим страницам сайта, возможно ли такое реализовать в Apache, потому что как я понимаю Apache одновременно выполняет только 1 скрипт, ждет его завершения, а только потом переходит к обработке следующего скрипта, если я правильно понимаю?

P.S. Обращался с таким вопросом к тех поддержке хостинга, посоветовали оптимизировать скрипт, но что это значит, нужно разбить логику скрипта на несколько частей чтобы была меньше нагрузка на сервер, но такими темпами общее время выполнения скрипта будет ведь больше?

P.S.S. Запустить скрипт через консоль php как я понимаю тоже нельзя, т.к. скрипт привязан к движку сайта - symfony, а запускать через консоль можно только одиночные скрипты?

Comment: Что за магическая привязка к движку сайта, что этот скрипт не может выполнить другой веб сервер или консоль?